# C# wrapper for Winsock 2 DLL?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, pinvoke, winsock2

Now that Silverlight 5 (RC) supports [P/Invoke](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/04/the-big-list-of-whats-new-or-improved-in-silverlight-5), I am thinking of implementing a Socket class with server functionality, i.e. a class that implements the Bind, Listen, Accept methods, etc. With P/Invoke, I would be able to access the socket methods in ws2_32.dll from my Silverlight class library.

If possible, I would like to get a head start. It's a long-shot, but: has anyone implemented a C# wrapper to the Winsock 2 DLL, and in that case, is this effort publicly available?

The [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono) project of course provides its own [Socket](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs) implementation in C#, but this code comes with a little bit of overhead, to say the least. I am looking for a more light-weight solution, if there is any.

Comment: I may be missing something, but is there any reason not to use the built-in System.Net.Sockets class?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

Comment: In Silverlight, The built-in Socket class does not support server methods such as Bind, Listen and Accept. With P/Invoke in Silverlight I would be able to implement a customized Socket class supporting these methods.

Comment: Silverlight isn't listed on the supported platforms (end of the page in your link)

Comment: I was missing something.  Thank you!

Comment: So, you want to open a listening socket in my browser. Thanks to virus scanners/browser securities that they don't allow this.

Comment: L.B., you should not be too worried about your browser. There are still quite a lot of restrictions for distributing Silverlight applications using P/Invoke and other functions related to security: http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure whether this is what you are looking for but on http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ws2_32.bind# you can find the signatures you are looking for, just look on the left side of the site for `ws2_32`

EDIT - after comments:

This http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4043&lngWId=10 seems to be a VB-implemented wrapper for Winsock2 which can be used by C# .

Comment: Thanks, Yahia. Yes, I know about pinvoke.net. For ws2_32 it is fairly incomplete. My hope is that someone has already gone through the effort of wrapping a larger number of the ws2_32 methods.

Comment: Thanks again, Yahia. I saw that one as well before writing to SO. I had a look at the code, but at first sight it is  not obvious to me if I can make any use of it. I will take a second look to see if I overlooked something the first time. Either way, I really appreciate your efforts with this.

Comment: I have looked more closely at the VB-socket wrapper now, and it appears to rely on an ActiveX component mswinsck.osx. This does not really seem like a desirable solution, so I will go for the manual P/Invoke declaration of the relevant methods in ws2_32.dll.